# Hosting a WCF with a SVC file ready

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to deploy a SP web part to a new SP server. I read that I need to set up a WCF Service first before I can deploy it. I have all the files used from the web part's first deployment and verified that, with a few line alterations, that the code should be fine to recompile on the new SP server.

The files already have a .svc file, which is verified to be fine.  I am trying to follow guides on hosting a WCF service and I'm a little lost on them since I already have the .svc. I know it's not as simple as dropping it in the /_vti_bin folder, so how do I proceed?

Note: I have no physical access to the server. I am connecting to it via Remote Desktop Connection.

Note 2: I am new to SharePoint, so if there's an "obvious" step chances are I don't know what it is.

Comment: You do not need to set up a WCF to deploy webparts to sharepoint. Use the SP-AddSolution and SP-InstallSolution on the server you want to install it on in the sharepoint powershell. Google them to figure out the syntax, or I could give you a script I wrote and you can replace it with what you need.

Comment: @Taugenichts I've tried that before, but I go a few errrors from that. I made more progress since then, and I probably didn't get proper syntax on it. If you could show me the script that would help me greatly. Also, what should I check before attempting it?

Comment: Sure. "Add-SPSolution C:\...\Whatever.wsp"  to get the solution added to the server.                                           And then "Install-SPSolution –Identity Whatever.wsp -GACDeployment" to get the thing installed. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Taugenichts Now I remember...the main problem is it keeps saying "The local farm is not accessible." I have read so many articles about this that I'm not sure what to check to make it accessible.

Comment: You can access the site though just fine and it works and you are on the machine that is running the sharepoint site; ie you're not trying to do this remotely, right?

Comment: @Taugenichts I need to edit my post to reflect this. but I am. I do not have physical access to this server. There has to be a way to do this remotely, yes?

Comment: Well stackoverflow wants me to move this to chat, but your rep isn't high enough so whatever, ha. No, unfortunately you need to run this from the box that you have the farm installed on. Could you send the webpart to someone who has access to the box along with the script to run it? The limitations of full trust deployment were actually mostly why Sharepoint was moved to a mainly javascript/partial trust model with 2013 for deployment. I suppose there could be a way to deploy a WCF to run the scripts remotely on the server for you, if that is what this service is doing.

Comment: Also if you could remote desktop to it, that would work. Copy the files and run the script on the remote desktop connection.

Comment: @Taugenichts You could post an Answer to keep this going, but I am using Remote Desktop Connection. I should have stated that from the start. So there should be a way to make local farm accessible while using RDP to connect to the server yes?

Comment: I'll wait for a moderator to tell me to move it, since we can't chat lol. But yes, remote desktop should work. So you log into remote desktop on the server that has sharepoint and then on that computer run the sharepoint powershell and it gives you that error? My only thought on that is that you do not have local administrator privileges on the server or are not part of the farm administrators group on the sharepoint site.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosting the service in IIS, then create an application and put the SVC file in the root of the application (along with the Web.config) and the assemblies in the bin folder.  So for example, if the application name (in IIS) is "MyWCFService", and it's physical location is at C:\intepub\wwwroot\MyWCFService, then the .svc file would go in the root - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWCFService\Service1.svc.

The address would be `http://servername/MyWCFService\Service1.svc`.

If you're not hosting the service in IIS, then the .svc file is not necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to host the service in IIS first by creating it in Visual Studio. Should I copy the .svc file and web.config files I have into the root folder? What bin folder are you referring to, because the app folder (where Service.svc and App_Code folder are) has no bin folder.

Comment: The bin folder is probably not visible in your solution (unless you choose Show All Files).  If you're building it in Visual Studio then the structure supplied in the project is fine.  You'll use the same structure when you deploy it to the destination server.

Answer (score 1):

Better not to use SVC files which are the legacy of ASP.NET, but to use config activation, like

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <!--This is to replace the standalone svc file whic is the legacy of asp.net web app.-->
    <add relativeAddress = "RealWorldServices/RealWorld.svc" service = "Fonlow.Demo.RealWorldService.Service1"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="Fonlow.Demo.RealWorldService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="authBehavior">

    <!-- Service Endpoints. A Service may provide multiple endpoints -->
    <!-- Not need to define host. Relative  -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="Fonlow.Demo.RealWorldService.IService1" bindingConfiguration="httpsBindingConfig">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>


    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

So you will get simpler deployment.

For more details, have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World

Comment: SVC files are **not** legacy.  File-less activation (which you describe) is an option to host WCF in IIS without having a SVC file, but they are by no means legacy.

Comment: Correct, SVC files are not legacy anymore and had become "new" since .NET 4 and IIS 7, and could be still handy in some deployment/operation scenarios.

Comment: They were never legacy to begin with - your comment doesn't make sense.  They've been a part of the WCF Framework since .NET 3.0.  File-less activation gives developers an option of hosting the service in IIS without a physical SVC file, but 4.0 and IIS 7 did not make them "new".

Comment: It sounds like it's better to use the SVC since I have one. So where do I go from there?